# cannot declare variable to be of type because the following virtual functions are abstract

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, interface, virtual

I have the following code

Classes.h

```
#ifndef CLASSES_H
#define CLASSES_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



template< class T1, class T2>
class class1
{
      public:
             virtual void method1(int) const =0;
             virtual void method2(class1&) const =0;
};


template< class T1>
class class2:public class1<T1,int>
{
      public:
             void method1(int) const;
             void method2(class2&) const;
};


template< class T1>
void class2<T1>::method1(int i) const
{
     cout<<"class2::method1 - before Call %i"<<endl;
     cout<<"class2::method1 - after Call"<<endl;
}

template< class T1>
void class2<T1>::method2(class2& c2) const
{
     cout<<"class2::method2 - before Call"<<endl;
     cout<<"class2::method2 - after Call"<<endl;
}

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Classes.h" 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    class2<int> c2;

    c2.method1(0);
    c2.method2(c2);

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Basically, C1 is an interface Class, therefore its methods are purely virtual. The proble am encountering is that Medhod2 passes and instance of the the class itself (which is class1 for the interface, and class2 for the class implementig such interface).

Therefore Method2 has signature

```
void method2(class1&) const;
```

in class1 and

```
void method2(class2&) const;
```

in class2.

This is the reason wihy I am getting the error below when compiling.

```
main.cpp: In function `int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:12: error: cannot declare variable `c2' to be of type `class2<int>'
main.cpp:12: error:   because the following virtual functions are abstract:
Classes.h:14: error:  void class1<T1, T2>::method2(class1<T1, T2>&) const [with
T1 = int, T2 = int]
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

How can I fix this issue?

Can somebody please let me know? Thanks.

Comment: Don't write `using namespace std;`. It defeats the purpose of having the standard library in a namespace. And, even more so, don't write it in a header; you'll screw up every programmer who tries to use your class.

Comment: @Pete Becker I know that. I used that just for the sake of this example. How you got any suggestion about my question?

Comment: I'm finding it fairly hard to figure out what's being asked here. What you appear to want to do can't be done in C++ but I suspect that if we knew your underlying needs a template or alternate virtual approach would solve your real problem. Can you elaborate on your real problem a bit more, rather than a tiny part of the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a **design problem**: `class1::method2(class1&) const` must work for *any* argument matching the bill, i.e. every reference to type `class1`. If `class2` can only implement `method2()` for arguments of type `class2`, it's incomplete not only syntactically but also logically: there is no way it can deal with the intended use

```
class2 A;
class1*B = method_returning_pter_to_class1_object();
A.method2(*B);                         // intended usage of virtual function
```

(If you didn't intend this type of usage, then your design in `class1` was flawed.)

Of course you can use a `dynamic_cast` to invoke special behaviour if the argument is actually of type `class2&`, i.e.

```
void class2::method(class1&x) const
{
  class2*x2 = dynamic_cast<class2*>(&x);
  if(x2)
    apply_method_taking_class2(*x2);
  else
    apply_method_for_other_than_class2_object(x);
}
```

but this may incur some run-time penalty.

Comment: The idea is to have class1 with void method1(class1& ) const; class2 with void method1(class2& ) const; class3 void method1(class3& ) const; class4 void method1(class4& ) const; .... classN with void method1(classN& ) const; - where clas1 is the interfarce class and class1, class2, class3,... classN are the classes implenting such interface. Honestly, your solution would compile file, but I think it would not be very clean. Have you got any other suggestions?

Comment: this means your design is faulty. think about a better design first.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the virtual signatures need to match (return types can be co-variant, but otherwise the signatures should be the same). Change class2's `void method2(class2&) const;` to `void method2(class1&) const;`.

Alternately, hide the virtual method and supply your replacement:

```
class class2
{
    // must be implemented since pure virtual, but now private
    void method2(class1&) const; 
public:
    void method1(int) const;
    void method2(class2&) const;
};
```

Comment: ok I undestand that. I myself wrote that in post. However the problem is that in class2::method2 the parmeter passed must be an instance of class2. Cannot be any other type of class derived from class1. Your solution is sintactically correct and would definetely compile; however the code would not be sematically correct. How you got any other suggetions?

Comment: @gerald There is no way to do what you want, because class2 doesn't follow the interface you just defined in class1. When using the interface, how do you know if you should pass class2, class3, or class4 as a parameter?

Comment: @Bo Persson I am thinking of some downcasting - upcasting mechanism to do this, but I am missing something to make it happen...

Comment: Updated answer above. In short: make the override private and supply a new function. But note, this is ugly design.